# r - soma de uma variável em relação aos valores de outra variável em um data frame

Tags: r, data.frame, soma

Tenho um dataframe com várias colunas. Como faço para somar os valores de uma coluna dentro de um elemento de outra variável?
Quero fazer isso para sumarizar os dados de cada espécie dentro de cada campanha.
Já tentei usar a função summarise do pacote plyr mas não deu certo. Pode ser porque coloquei os fatores incorretamente a função.

```js
campanha   especie   frequencia
   1          A         2
   1          A         1
   1          A         3
   1          A         5
   1          B         1
   1          B         2
   1          B         1
   1          B         6
   1          B         1
   1          C         3
   1          C         1
   1          C         8
   1          C         4
   2          A         2
   2          A         8
   2          A         4
   2          A         5
   2          B         4
   2          B         2
   2          B         6
   2          B         1
   2          C         3
   2          C         1
   2          C         9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outra maneira de fazer isto é com a pacote `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dados %>%
  group_by(campanha, especie) %>%
  summarise(sum(frequencia))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   campanha [?]
  campanha especie `sum(frequencia)`
     <int> <fct>               <int>
1        1 A                      11
2        1 B                      11
3        1 C                      16
4        2 A                      19
5        2 B                      13
6        2 C                      13
```

Note que eu agrupei os dados com a função `group_by` e indicando as variáveis de agrupamento. A seguir, eu utilizei `summarise` para informar que gostaria de somar a variável `frequencia` dentro dos agrupamentos criados.

Comment: Obrigada @Marcus Nunes! Deu certo. Mas você acha que tem diferença quando uso o pacote dplyr ou o plyr? Porque quando usei o pacote plyr, sumarizou todos os dados em um valor só. Mas quando limpei e usei o pacote dplyr deu certo.

Comment: Eu não sei usar o `plyr`, então infelizmente não posso opinar. O que sei é o `dplyr` é mais novo e se os dois pacotes forem carregados simultaneamente, podem ocorrer erros na sessão do R.

Comment: @MarcusNunes A partir dessa resposta, se eu quisesse somar todas as linhas, ou seja, somar as respostas de A com B com C? 11+11+16+19....

Answer (score 2):

Isso pode ser resolvido com a função `aggregate`.

```
res <- aggregate(frequencia ~ campanha + especie, dados, sum)
res
#  campanha especie frequencia
#1        1       A         11
#2        2       A         19
#3        1       B         11
#4        2       B         13
#5        1       C         16
#6        2       C         13
```

**Dados em formato dput().**

```
dados <-
structure(list(campanha = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    especie = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L
    ), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), frequencia = c(2L, 
    1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 
    5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 9L)), .Names = c("campanha", 
"especie", "frequencia"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```